# best comparison algorithm for finding meeting times . (Dictionary collection)

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I.m using c# language .I have a dictionary. the key is string of peoples emails. The value for each key is a list of objects. Those objects has 2 dateTime variables start and End.

What I'm trying to do is finding when is the time that all people I have are free. in addition to finding the times if some of them are available.

I managed to solve the first part which when all users are available. However, since I'm using a linear search the code is really slow.

so my questions are:

1. What is the better algorithm for doing this kind of comparison, keep in mind I'm comparing date ranges.
2. What is the best way to find if some of them are available at a specific time ??

This is the method responsible for intersection

```
private static FreeTime Intersection(FreeTime first, FreeTime second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside intersection " + first.Start + " "+ first.End + " sescond " + second.Start + " " + second.End);
            int result1 = DateTime.Compare(first.Start, second.End);
            int result2 = DateTime.Compare(first.End, second.Start);
            int result3 = DateTime.Compare(first.Start, second.Start);
            int result4 = DateTime.Compare(first.End, second.End);
            Boolean equal = (result3 == 0 && result4 == 0);

            if (!(result1 >= 0) && !(result2 <= 0) && !equal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(Math.Max(first.Start.Ticks, second.Start.Ticks)).TimeOfDay + "min max" + new DateTime(Math.Min(first.End.Ticks, second.End.Ticks)).TimeOfDay);

                return new FreeTime(new DateTime(Math.Max(first.Start.Ticks, second.Start.Ticks)), new DateTime(Math.Min(first.End.Ticks, second.End.Ticks)));

            }

            else if (result3 == 0 && result4 == 0)
                return (new FreeTime(first.Start, first.End));

            else return null;
```

---

This part is for iterating through the lists

```
foreach (var t in allFree)
            {
                if (allFree != null)///&& list.Count > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Start + " " + t.End + " in all freeeee");
                    foreach (var s in allFree)
                    {
                        if (!((DateTime.Compare(t.Start.Date, s.Start.Date) == 0) && (DateTime.Compare(t.Start, s.Start) == 0) && (DateTime.Compare(t.End, s.End) == 0)) && (t.Start.Date == s.Start.Date))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("callling inteersection 2 ");
                            intersection = Intersection(t, s);
                        }
                        // else if ((list.Count == list2.Count) && ((DateTime.Compare(t.Start.Date, s.Start.Date) == 0) && (DateTime.Compare(t.Start, s.Start) == 0) && (DateTime.Compare(t.End, s.End) == 0)) && (t.Start.Date == s.Start.Date))
                        //  intersection = new FreeTime(t.Start, t.End);

                        if (intersection != null)
                        {
                            finalFree.Add(intersection);
                            Console.WriteLine(intersection.Start + " " + intersection.End + " intersection result");
                            intersecFound = true;
                        }

                    }//end foreach
                    if (!intersecFound)
                    {
                        // allFree.Add(t);
                        intersecFound = false;
                    }
```

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Does date component of DateTime matter or are you just interested in time component. For example, can user be "busy" from 2015-06-20 11:00 until 2015-06-23 16:00, or you need to check just time no matter what the date is?

Comment: I need to check the date as well